# javascript: reading lang attribute in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In `<html>` tag I have attribute `lang`. How do I reach it using .js. I want to use contains of lang as a variable. So as I understand it should start with `var lang = ???`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
    var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
    alert(theLanguage);
```

If you wanna fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NX367/

If you want to do it in plain Javascript, this site will explain better than I:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml

Comment: what alert does? sorry i don't have a lot of exp. with .js

Comment: alert() will do a little dialog window (like an "ok" box), but obviously you can do other things with `theLanguage` as well

Answer (score 21):

Pure js way

```
var lang = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ZRvE6/

Comment: heh yeah, Im trying to work out a bug with it in IE8. Both are valid answers, I didnt see he had the question tagged as jquery as well.

Comment: Or `document.documentElement.getAttribute('lang')`, which may look cleaner to some people.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to retrieve the `lang` attribute is to access the `lang` property on the read-only [`documentElement` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) on the `document` object:

```
document.documentElement.lang;
```