# Plugin options - how to create multiple sets of options

Tags: jquery

I'm using a plugin for a multiple select box. In theory this questions would go for any other plugin with options.
The plugin has some options, language strings among others. I would like to create a set of options based on language - in this case on the `<html lang="">` attribute.

I have tried with this:

```
var multipleSelectLang = function() {
    var da = {
        placeholder: 'V&aelig;lg flere...',
        selectAllText: 'V&aelig;lg alle',
        width: '100%'
    };
    var en = {
        placeholder: 'Select multiple...',
        width: '100%'
    };
    return ($('html:lang(en)')) ? en : da;
};
$('select[multiple]').multipleSelect(multipleSelectLang());
```

So depending on `<html lang="en">` or `<html lang="da">` it should run the plugin with the corresponding options.
As you can see in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ddtpxzh/), it displays the English option even though the language is set to `"da"`.

I hope my question makes sense. Any ideas what is wrong?

```js
$('html').attr("lang", "da");
// Multiple select functions - work fine.
// $('select[multiple]').multipleSelect({
//   placeholder: "V&aelig;lg flere...",
//   selectAllText: 'V&aelig;lg alle',
//   width: '100%'
// });
var multipleSelectLang = function() {
  var da = {
    placeholder: 'V&aelig;lg flere...',
    selectAllText: 'V&aelig;lg alle',
    width: '100%'
  };
  var en = {
    placeholder: 'Select multiple...',
    width: '100%'
  };
  return ($('html:lang(en)')) ? en : da;
};
$('select[multiple]').multipleSelect(multipleSelectLang());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can execute `$('html:lang(en)')` in browser tools, the result is an object, no boolean. I'm not familar with the plugin, maybe test `$('html:lang(en)').length > 0` instead of boolean test?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031531/javascript-reading-lang-attribute-in-html-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
$('html').attr("lang", "da");
// Multiple select functions - work fine.
// $('select[multiple]').multipleSelect({
//   placeholder: "V&aelig;lg flere...",
//   selectAllText: 'V&aelig;lg alle',
//   width: '100%'
// });
var multipleSelectLang = {
  da: {
    placeholder: 'V&aelig;lg flere...',
    selectAllText: 'V&aelig;lg alle',
    width: '100%'
  },
  en: {
    placeholder: 'Select multiple...',
    width: '100%'
  }
}
$('select[multiple]').multipleSelect(multipleSelectLang[$("html").attr("lang")||"en"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```